# PHP Convert Local time to UTC DateTime

Tags: php, codeigniter, datetime

I want to convert my local timezone dateTime to UTC timezone DateTime.

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$datetime = "2016-05-05 18:33:00";
echo date_default_timezone_get()."<br>"; // Asia/Calcutta
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date_default_timezone_get()."<br>"; //UTC
echo $utcDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($datetime));
```

**Current Output**

```
2016-05-05 18:33:00
```

But, Problem is do not convert local dateTime to UTC dateTime. It will give output as Local DateTime.

Comment: Pls comment for downvote

Comment: The question of comments + downvotes has been discussed ad nauseum on Meta. Many folks just choose to DV and move on. Many offer advice. Many try to light the path for newbies. But checking the OP's track record leads some to run from their questions because they may not be worth the effort.

Comment: Pass the date to `strtotime` before you set the timezone to UTC.

Comment: ***Pro tip:*** Do not act needy and do not say your requirement is urgent. The folks answering questions are volunteers with busy lives, just like yours.

Comment: Thank you @MacMac It's working like charm

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will need to pass the date to `strtotime` before you change the timezone with `date_default_timezone_set`. Like so:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$datetime = "2016-05-05 18:33:00";
$asia_timestamp = strtotime($datetime);
echo date_default_timezone_get()."<br>"; // Asia/Calcutta
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
echo date_default_timezone_get()."<br>"; //UTC
echo $utcDateTime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $asia_timestamp);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood it well, it should work:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-05-05 18:33:00');
# you could to pass in timezone too
# $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s', '2016-05-05 18:33:00',
#     new DateTimeZone('America/Fortaleza'));

var_dump($date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC')));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [date helper](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/date_helper.html):

```
local_to_gmt($time = '');

// $gmt = local_to_gmt(time());
```

> Takes a UNIX timestamp as input and returns it as GMT.

[Docs](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/helpers/date_helper.html#local_to_gmt).

Comment: Just wondered who could downvote. I'd like to see explanation, thanks.

Comment: I looked into this and found that the conversion you made works in Codeigniter and won't work in vanilla PHP, ultimately your answer become invalid. Hope that's why someone downvoted.

Comment: @Balaji.J.B Followed tag in question which clearly said CodeIgniter. Further more description is in link I posted. However, OP has solved problem eventually.